# NodeJS Include RPIO npm error not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, settimeout, gpio

I have a node.js application with two folder backend and src for frontend, with individual node_modules folder.

The problem is that I have a script in backend that requires library "rpio" all good it runs exceptionally.

I have installed also this library into src folder because I need it also in another file, when I try to require the library and run npm run build all runs good except when i npm start and I receive a blank page with the following error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at t.getFileName (bindings.js:143:1)
    at t (bindings.js:59:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (rpio.js:16:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (rpio.js:1393:1)
    at f ((index):1:1111)
    at 172 (Preferences.js:6:12)
    at f ((index):1:1111)
    at 54 (index.js:18:26)
    at f ((index):1:1111)
    at a ((index):1:980)
```

bindings.js - line 143

```
  if (fileName.indexOf(fileSchema) === 0) {
    fileName = fileURLToPath(fileName);
  }
```

bindings.js - line 59

```
  if (!opts.module_root) {
    opts.module_root = exports.getRoot(exports.getFileName());
  } // Ensure the given bindings name ends with .node
```

rpio.js - line 16

```
var binding = require('bindings')('rpio');
```

rpio.js - line 1393

```
rpio.prototype.usleep = function (usecs) {
  bindcall(binding.rpio_usleep, usecs);
};
```

Could someone help me with some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you calling `var binding = require('bindings')('rpio');` ?

Comment: This is from the rpio library, not mine. The same library on the other files works great.

Comment: I can't see your whole code of `bindings.js` which I assume is yours, but the error log is clear: `fileName` is undefined

Comment: The bindings.js is the library that rpio need this is not my whole code. My code is in Preferences.js which is just var rpio = require("rpio");

This is bindings.js which is a library: https://pastebin.com/UtykUXQx

This is rpio.js which is also a library: https://pastebin.com/VJcYnx9u